# How to get Gluon SceneBuilder working with Fedora 25?

Tags: fedora

http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

Works perfectly on every version of Fedora back to 20, but results in the following error on Fedora 25 under Wayland:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  148 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2
  Serial number of failed request:  30
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

It doesn't matter if you use the RPM package, or try to manually start it with

```
java -jar SceneBuilder-8.2.0.jar
```

It all comes back to the same error message. Anyone know how to rectify this?

Comment: Are you using wayland or X11?

Comment: I am using Wayland; if I log off and log back in under X11, everything works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SceneBuilder 8.3.0 works correctly under Fedora 25 & Wayland.

However, it is not High DPI aware, I'm running 3200x1800, and everything is too small under Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of features relatee to the GUI does not work under wayland yet and if an application fails to handle it correctly, it crashes.

As an workaround, you can log into your account with old X11 (choose GNOME on X in the login screen).